# Why would this loop infinitely? (Java)

Tags: java, insert, linked-list, infinite-loop

I am trying to make an add method for a linked list, but for some reason (that is not obvious to me, in fact I came here to get help finding the error) it goes into an infinite loop every time.

EDIT: I found the error, and I will keep my original code with a comment with the corrected code

```
public void insert(String majorName)
{
    MajorNode newNode = new MajorNode(majorName, 1);
    boolean inList = false;
    MajorNode current = first;

    if(isEmpty())
    {
        first = newNode;
                    // inList = true;
    }
    else
    {
        while(current.next != null)
        {
            if(current.majorName.equalsIgnoreCase(majorName))
            {
                current.frequency++;
                inList = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                current = current.next;
            }
        }
    }

    if(!inList)
    {
        newNode.next = first;
        first = newNode;
    }
}
```

Here is my node class if it is needed:

```
public class MajorNode 
{
    public String majorName;
    public int frequency;
    public MajorNode next;

    public MajorNode(String majorName, int frequency)
    {
        this.majorName = majorName;
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return majorName + " " + frequency;
    }
}
```

Comment: No my only question is, does this update each item's frequency correctly? Thank you everyone.

Comment: You're 100% sure your list didn't get a cycle in it somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the first call to `insert()`, one assumes `isEmpty()` returns true and consequently `first` is set to the `newNode` before `newNode`'s `next` field is set to the previous (null) value of `first`.  Thus, when the list is non-empty, the loop iterates indefinitely on the last element in the list whose `next` field points to itself.

Out of curiosity, why are you trying to implement your own linked list functionality rather than build upon available packages (such as [java.util.LinkedList<E>](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html))?

Comment: For an algorithms class, I just wanted to do that as a part of my final project, plus my insert method can't insert a new object into the list if it already exists in the list. It should just increment the frequency of that item.

Comment: No problem; but perhaps then it should be tagged homework, as such an approach would be ill-advised in most real world situations?  To answer your revised question, I believe the corrected code should indeed maintain a frequency count.

Comment: Just out of curiosity , this wouldn't be good production code because it uses a self made data structure? Or is it just bad coding? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The former, but maybe it's just personal preference: I try to avoid reinventing the wheel wherever possible, as I feel it's more likely that a widely used library will work as intended than anything proprietary created for a single purpose; it's also often easier to read, as a lot of code can be drastically reduced into one or two well understood library calls.

Answer (score 2):

When you create the first node you do this:

```
if(!inList)
{        
    newNode.next = first;        
    first = newNode;    
}
```

This points the first nodes next at itself... hence a loop

You should be leaving the newNode.next as null for the first node, so that when you insert the second item, you reach the end of the chain..

Answer (score 1):

You will have an wrong frequency if you add a node which is similar to the last node of your List. Consider this situation (adding 2 similar nodes in the empty list)

1. You will add a node1 in a blank list. So first & current will point to node1. (but node1.next will be null)
2. If you add the same node (or a node with a same `majorName`), you will reach to while loop (because List is not empty now). And also, you will not enter into a while loop as well. (as your current.next is still null)
   and you will end up with two noes with same `majorName` in your list.

I would suggest to use

```
while(current != null)
```

instead of

```
while(current.next != null)
```

Comment: Good spot.  And another thought: frequency is not incremented/set when inserting a new node into the list.

Comment: @eggyal, I am sorry, but I didn't got _frequency is not incremented/set when inserting a new node into the list_ . I think frequency is being passed as a constructor parameter and there is no need to set is explicitly for a new node.. correct me if I am wrong.